# Facebook posts using Facebook API

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using python 3.7

I would like to access all comments available through the facebook api based on a search criteria. I have created a developer account and started playing around with [pyfacebook](https://pypi.org/project/python-facebook-api/) and [facebook-sdk](https://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html). Currently, I have only been able to access content on pages I have admin rights to, by using [this posts](https://medium.com/@DrGabrielA81/python-how-making-facebook-api-calls-using-facebook-sdk-ea18bec973c8#6d94) and [this one](https://medium.com/@DrGabrielA81/python-how-getting-facebook-data-and-insights-using-facebook-sdk-9de14d3c12fb).

I haven't been able to find out what I need to do to effectively search facebook for some terms of interest and collect all the comments for each object that come out.

Example: I would like to [search the facebook](https://www.facebook.com/search/top/?q=airlines&epa=SEARCH_BOX) page for 'airlines', and then get all the comments for each of the posts and public groups that are listed. I would be happy with just the comments from the posts if necessary.

I would like to do some sentiment analysis and possibly topic identification.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: That is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to search for posts or comments in general, you can only get posts of specific Pages and search in those on your own - either by using a Page Token or by applying for [Page Public Content Access](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature/#reference-PAGES_ACCESS) for Pages you do not own.

Answer (score 0):

According to facebook API docs:

> The Page Public Content Access Feature is required to request publicly shared posts of Pages that you are not an admin of.

More information [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature/#reference-PAGES_ACCESS)